# hook_update_N() for more than 100 updates or 10 major releases

Tags: hooks

The documentation for [hook_update_N()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x) says the following:

> Implementations of hook_update_N() are named (module name)*update*(number). The numbers are composed of three parts:
>
> - 1 digit for Drupal core compatibility.
> - 1 digit for your module's major release version (e.g., is this the 7.x-1.* (1) or 7.x-2.* (2) series of your module?). This digit should be 0 for initial porting of your module to a new Drupal core API.
> - 2 digits for sequential counting, starting with 00.

These are hypothetical questions:

What happens if you get to something like 7299? Are you required to release a major version update next even if you don't implement the hook, or if you do?

What happens if you have a lot of branches or major releases and get to something like 8900 and want to release a new one for that version of Drupal... 8(10)00? I know some modules go from 7.x-3.x to 8.x-4.x, so this could potentially happen if they continue in that way.

Comment: It's just a number, really, a convention; it isn't validated against the current version of the module or anything. The digit count also isn't enforced (`foo_update_8101000` is valid, for example), but it's easy to introduce ambiguity if you go to extremes. Take `811123`. Is that major version 11 and minor 123, or major version 1 and minor 1123?

Comment: So in the event of the ambiguity, would it still be invoked correctly? I don't know where the hooks are invoked from.

Comment: Yep it'll be invoked, first time (so for version 1.1123 in the above example), but then if/when you get to version 11.123, the function name would be the same, so you can't use it again. You could skip a version, 11.124, but then you may have already had a 1.1124, and so on. Quite messy, and that's just one example of the, I'm sure many, possible collisions. In short, unless I'm missing something, it doesn't seem to be a system that supports what you're proposing very well

Comment: So it just concatenates {major}{minor} and invokes if it hasn't been invoked yet? Also, you could probably write an answer.

Comment: It's much looser than that, the contents of the .install file literally have a regular expression run against them to find functions with an integer at the end, and those are sorted in order. The updater then runs through those, starting at the first update function whose number is greater than the module's current saved schema version, and processes them. Those numbers don't have to be sequential. I can't put a decent answer in right now but I'll try to later

Comment: See [`update_get_update_list()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21update.inc/function/update_get_update_list/8.7.x) and [`drupal_get_schema_versions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21schema.inc/function/drupal_get_schema_versions/8.7.x) for the nitty-gritty

Answer (score 0):

The one time I dealt with this, I just kept on going. After 7199, I moved to 71100, then 71101 etc. It wasn't a problem (Drupal 7).